# VB.net Database connections a little off

Tags: database, events, vb.net-2010

I hope this doesn't have a terribly easy solution but I couldn't find a similar problem around the internet.

I have a few disabled textBoxes and a comboBox that is hooked up to my database all fine and dandy.  The comboBox selects which ID I want displayed and the rest fills up real nice like.  My problem is that I'm having trouble finding an event that works with the newly repopulated textBoxes for calculations.

I have 3 fields that are pulling from the database, ID, Name, and Price.  If there is a number in a quantity text box it does calculateCost() .  When I change the comboBox containing my ID I want it to go to calculateCost() again.  _SelectedIndexChanged does the calculateCost() after ID is updated, but before the rest of the fields are updated, so it is using the previous ID's price rather than the new one. _Validating and _Validated on either the ID or the price fields never fire, I guess that database info is allowed willy nilly.  I can't find a work around to this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier to figure out your issue if you can post your code.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty solution, if you can't find another, is to add a timer that calls your calculate cost function and set it to fire a short while after your combo box event. It's not an elegant way but it gets the job done.